# JavaFx how to check time every 1 hour

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to write a simple JavaFx program, which suppose to check time and every full hour do something(at first only change the text in label). But I have a problem with constantly checking the time. I'm using a Calendar class.
If I write a while(true) loop, the program starts but doesn't do anything.
Should I use threads?
I know it's probably trivial issue, but I can't figure it out, I'm kind of new in this;p

Thanks guys for help(I didn't know whether I should reply below or edit this post).
I managed to create my own version, which I based on link, you gave me.

```
public class Trening extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            Calendar tajm = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = tajm.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minutes = 0;
            updateMessage(Integer.toString(hour));
            while (true) {
                try {
                    minutes = 60 - tajm.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    Thread.sleep(minutes * 60000);
                    if (tajm.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) != hour) {
                        hour = tajm.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        updateMessage(Integer.toString(hour));

                    } else {

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    //System.err.print("...");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Label btn = new Label();
    btn.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("...");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Like I said I'm rather new to programming, so I appreciate every piece of advice.
Thank you very much for your help, and if you have any more advice to what I have written, I wouldn't mind;p

And sorry I didn't marked your answers as useful, but I have too low reputation...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JavaFX.  You are asking how to use features of the Java Calendar API, not how to adapt your data to a GUI.

Comment: Well not exactly, when I run simple application, not Javafx application, I don't have this problem. While loop starts normally and continues, just like I want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach.

First, encapsulate your periodic task.

```
public static class MyPeriodicTask implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        boolean fullHour = ... // determine somehow
        if (fullHour) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // Modify label here
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `Platform.runLater()` call, this quarantees that passed `Runnable` will be executed by the JavaFX application thread, where you can safely interact with the GUI.

Then use the an `ExecutorService` to run your task periodically

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyPeriodicTask(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This will run your task in every minute (after 1 minute initial delay).

But if you are serious about JavaFX, then I think you should read [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) at least.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started, do note I used a Service. A Task would probably better for this.
It's been a while since I wrote Java but by following [this guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) I was able to quickly create the sample below.

It also uses the Calendar library, I hope you find it useful.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;


import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;



public class StackOverflow_001 <T extends Comparable<T>> extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args); // Launches the application
    }

            // A simple service with an internal clock.
    private static class HourService extends Service<Date>
    {

        private Calendar calendar;

        public final void setCalendarInstance(Calendar c)
        {
            calendar = c;
        }


        @Override
        protected Task<Date> createTask() {

            return new Task<Date>() {

                protected Date call()
                {
                    int secondsdelay = 5;
                    Date timeStarted = calendar.getTime();
                    Date timeEnd = new Date(timeStarted.getTime() + 1000 * secondsdelay );//* 60 * 60);

                    while( timeEnd.after(calendar.getTime()) )
                    {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("---");
                            System.out.println("Time: " + calendar.getTime());
                            System.out.println("End:  " +timeEnd);

                            Thread.sleep(500);
                            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            if (isCancelled()) {
                                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Service ended.");
                    return timeEnd;

                }
            };
        }


    }

            // Sets up everything and creates the window.
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        final VBox root = new VBox();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));

        final Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());

        root.getChildren().add(btn1);

        final HourService hservice = new HourService();
        hservice.setCalendarInstance(Calendar.getInstance());
        hservice.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() { // Anonymous

            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                btn1.setText(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString());
                hservice.restart();
            }
        });

        hservice.start();

        primaryStage.show();

    }


}
```